# sql - merging several rows in one table from the same table based on same value on two columns but different rows

Tags: sql-server, join, merge, duplicates

SQL - I have one table with many columns and high number of rows. Table has ID_PK in column C1. 3 columns (C4, C5, C6) contain 'names'. The other rows contain other data. 'names' can have duplicates between them (for example: one name in column C4, row 168 can have a duplicate in column C5, row 247). When there is a value in C4 then C5 and C6 are NULL and viceversa.

I need to find the duplicates between C4, C5 and C6 (no matter in which row), and merge the row 186 and 247 into one, keeping all data in all columns for both 168 and 247, creating an additional column 'NEW_NAMES' to be populated by the value of C4 with all the subsequent data related to both C4 and C5 (in the example, all data that is in both row 168 and 247).

Example:

Table T1:

'
id pk  ' column 1   ' column 4   '    column 5    ' column 6    '   column 7    '   col c...  '

--------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------

00186   |  info g....     |... name1... |   NULL ...  |   NULL |  NULL | etc

...xyz   | ...NULL.. |   ...NULL.... |   NULL.. | name2 |  NULL | etc

00247 | NULL...  |   ....NULL ...|  name1..|  ... NULL |   info h

Output should be:

id  pk |   c1   |   c4     |    c5    |    c6    |    c7   | NEW_NAME

----+------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------

nnn |   g   | name1 | name1|   NULL  |    h    |  name1

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your sample data is so difficult to decipher I can't figure out what you want here. And your desired output doesn't seem to line up with your sample data at all. Can you post table definitions as create table, sample data and inserts and then desired output for the sample data provided?

Comment: Yes, as @SeanLange said, this example data is indecipherable. It seems pretty clear you have a highly complex problem you are seeking help with, but nobody is going to want or be able to do that until you take a more organized approach.

Comment: Thanks both. I had to split the table and move on from there to get it done. I'll try to be more detailed in my next post.